# Why I cant print a vector or matrix?

Tags: c

I've tried everything to print my vector between functions, but for some reason when the vector or matrix is filled, when leaving the vector or matrix the data of this is erased, so when it's printed it does it with garbage random data.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void menu();
void fillVector1(int vector[], int size);
void fillVector2(int vector[], int size);
void fillVector3(int vector[], int vector1[], int vector2[], int size);
void fillMatrix(int matrix[][5], int size);
void printVector(int vector[], int size);
void printMatrix(int matrix[][5], int size);

int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    int option;
    int vector1[10];
    int vector2[10];
    int vector3[20];
    int matrix[5][5];

    printf("ARRAYS MENU");
    printf("\n\t1.- Fill Vector 1\n\t2.- Fill Vector 2\n\t3.- Fill Vector 3\n\t4.- Print Vectors\n\t5.- Fill Matrix 4x4\n\t6.- Print Matrix\n\t0.- Close Program\n");
    printf("Select an option: ");
    scanf("%i", &option);

    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
        fillVector1(vector1, 10);
        break;
    case 2:
        fillVector2(vector2, 10);
        break;
    case 3:
        fillVector3(vector3, vector1, vector2, 10);
        printVector(vector3, 10);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("\n");
        printVector(vector1, 10);
        printf("\n");
        printVector(vector2, 10);
        printf("\n");
        printVector(vector3, 20);
        break;
    case 5:
        fillMatrix(matrix, 4);
        break;
    case 6:
        printMatrix(matrix, 4);
        break;
    case 0:
        printf("Thanks for using this program. Come back soon!");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid option. Select another one.");
        break;
    }
}

void fillVector1(int vector[], int size)
{
    printf("Fill it only with numbers between 30 to 70\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Vector[%i]: ", i);
        scanf("%i", &vector[i]);

        if (vector[i] < 30 || vector[i] > 70)
        {
            printf("Value out of range. Please enter another number.\n");
            i--; // repeat last (incorrect) index
        }
    }
    menu();
}

void fillVector2(int vector[], int size)
{
    printf("Vector filled with random numbers between 1 to 20");

    int checkRepeated;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        // function to avoid repeated number
        do
        {
            checkRepeated = 0; // initialize to assume the number is not repeated
            vector[i] = rand() % 20 + 1;

            // check if the random number already exists in the vector
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (vector[j] == vector[i])
                {
                    checkRepeated = 1; // set to 1 if the number is repeated
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (checkRepeated); // repeat until a unique number is generated
    }
    menu();
}

void fillVector3(int vector[], int vector1[], int vector2[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = vector1[i];
        vector[i + 10] = vector2[i];
    }
    menu();
}

void fillMatrix(int matrix[][5], int size)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
        {
            printf("Matrix[%i, %i]: ", r, c);
            scanf("%i", &matrix[r][c]);
        }
    }
    menu();
}

void printVector(int vector[], int size)
{
    printf("Vector elements: {");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", vector[i]);
        if (i < size - 1)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("}");
}

void printMatrix(int matrix[][5], int size)
{
    int r, c;

    printf("Matrix elements: \n{\n");
    for (r = 0; r < size; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < size; c++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("}");
}
```

Don't know why it is not printing the correct data bc all the 'fill' functions are correct. Hope you can help me guys.

Comment: Remove the recursive calls to `menu()` from the bottom of each function. Let the function end and automatically return to the point at which the function was called.

Comment: Function calls isn't some glorified `goto`. All of your problems are caused by incorrect use of function calls. You'll need to take a few steps back from this program and study how functions work, then rewrite everything accordingly.

Comment: You'll probably want to put the prompt, user input and dispatch (most of the function body) of `menu()` inside some kind of `for( ;; )` loop... When the user enters option `0`, say good bye and perform `return;` (not `break;`) to bounce back to `main()`...

Comment: You need to read a bit more about storage, lifetime and visibility of variables. On each recursive call of `menu` you get a *different* set of your arrays. You cannot access the variables from the calling instance of `menu`. That is why you need to get rid of your recursion.

Comment: I removed all tags except C, because the actual problem here is exclusively incorrect usage of function calls.

Comment: Apply what Fe2O3 suggests and remove all calls to `menu()` except the one in the `main` function and then your code should work. There may be other issues though, I didn't check.

Comment: Thanks, I found the way to compile it correctly, all the problem was in the badly implemented menu and the wrong way to call the functions.